# How to convert mercurial strip/histedit/rebase backup to patch files?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Mercurial backs up the commits/changesets for every destroy operation like histedit, rebase and strip. In my case, it has lots of such files.

How to convert these files with .hg extension to patches so that we can examine their contents?

I have looked at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ManuallyUnpackingStripBundle, but it doesn't help.

```py
import os
import glob
import bz2

for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join('hg-cs-bundles', '*.hg')):
    i = 1
    with open(filepath) as f:
        content = f.read()
        b = bz2.decompress("BZ" + content[6:])
        open(str(i)+".patch", "w").write(b)
        i = i + 1
```

```
python convert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 9, in <module>
    b = bz2.decompress("BZ" + content[6:])
IOError: invalid data stream
```

Comment: I'd just read the commits back into a repository (perhaps a clone), where they will resume their status as perfectly good commits. (Use `hg unbundle` or `hg pull` from the bundle file to do this.) However, you can also use them with the `-R` option: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LookingIntoBundles